# Where do the hinge knuckles go on these fold down table legs?

Tags: woodworking, workshop

https://youtu.be/e9GSTO-4Txo?t=119 is a This Old House fold down workbench (among other things). The knuckle of the leg hinge (at 1:59) appears to be pointed into the 2x4 of the table top frame. If so, how did they get the hinge to lay flat? I'm talking about the leaf that goes against the table top, and not really the table top, just the frame.

It seems to me they could have used a shim to support part of the hinge; although, I see no evidence. So maybe it's a special hinge, a hinge that's different than what I have?

Comment: It looks like a standard hinge to me.

Comment: It seams pretty clear in the video and any thing Tom Silva does is done correctly.  There is no need to rethink this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the outside edge of the knuckle is flush with the hinge plate attached to the table top, like this (side view):

[image]

Comment: Yes, this must be the answer.  I just thought I would get a peak at the other leaf at https://youtu.be/e9GSTO-4Txo?t=331 or https://youtu.be/e9GSTO-4Txo?t=336

Comment: Maybe the leg leaf is in a mortise in the leg.